# Website requests not reaching IIS?

Tags: iis, asp.net

To start off with a confession, I am not a server admin - just a developer tasked with getting to the root of a problem. Please be gentle!

I have an intranet ASP.NET website running in IIS on a virtual machine. The website is not accessed very often (the last IIS log file was modified nearly six months ago). Both the IP address and Host header value are now failing to return the website, and the IIS log still doesn't show any more recent activity.

The virtual machine was moved to a different physical location a few months ago, and the IP address for it has changed. Could this be what has broken access to the site? What else should I be checking to solve this?

I don't have totally unrestricted access to the building's network settings, structures, etc. I would be grateful for any advice, even if I can't use it myself it'll improve my knowledge of what's going on behind the scenes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the bindings on the web site, is it set to (All Unassigned) or is it set to the new ip address of the server? Has the new ip address been added to the server? (I'm assuming yes based on your information). Is the firewall setup to NAT an external ip address to the internal ip address of the server? Is the firewall setup to allow web traffic to the server?

Comment: +1 on checking the bindings, if it was ever set to just listen on the old IP address, then it will still just be listening on that address.

Comment: It was the DNS settings in the end, needed to get a network admin to go and check that one. The new IP addresses hadn't been added to the server either!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help...